# How to change OpenStack Swift source code to test my research idea?

Tags: cloud, open-source, openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage

I am a graduate student and I want to do some researches on Swift Object Storage. I have installed **SAIO - Swift All In One** on my Ubuntu VM. I want to change the Swift source code to test my idea. How should I start to change the source code and test my idea? Can I change the Swift source code in my VM directly and then restart Swift service?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can but what exactly you trying to do ?

Comment: I am so sorry for the late reply. I want to change the ways of object organizations in the Swift. Will it work?

Comment: Can you elaborate it more ? What do you mean by "changing the ways of object organizations in the swift" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it for studying and testing purpose: change the code and restart it.

For real use purpose, I **HIGHLY** recommend you don't. Openstack Swift is distributed and complex storage system and I recommend you to get in touch with its friendly community before changing anything.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and really appreciate your help!!! After changing the source code, just restart swift is enough for the test. correct?

Comment: Yes. If for any reason you don't see any difference, clean the python cache files.

Comment: Thanks, that is so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make the changes to the code and restart the swift services.Make sure that you restart the swift services in the server where you have made changes but in some cases you might have to restart the controller node services too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the openstack python code directly. After restarting the service, you can see your code working.

I will recommend using devstack, if you are planned to create your own plugin.Your services will run as screens in devstack.